# Быть и страдательное причастие настоящего времени

Tags: грамматика

Обычно страдательный залог несовершенного вида образуется с помощью частицы **-ся**.

Но я вот думаю: имеет ли в таком случае конструкция *быть + ст. пр. наст.* другое значение? Или, может, такая конструкция вообще не используется?

Например: *экзамен (есть) сдаваем(ый) учеником*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a widely used construct in Church Slavonic but is not normally used in modern Russian, except with some verbs which can't form reflexive or change their meaning in reflexive form: *любить, судить* etc:

> Он был любим богами
>
> Он был неоднократно судим федеральным судом

You can find it in some older texts though:

> - Вот почему ребёнок благодаря своей необычной впечатлительности **должен быть оберегаем** от всего, что так или иначе может пагубно отразиться на его детской природе. // *[В. М. Бехтерев. Внушение и воспитание (1911)]*
> - У славянофилов оно выражалось только в более резкой форме и **эпигонами их было доводимо** до крайности; например, К. Н. Леонтьев чуть не прославлял русского человека за то, что ему чужда «вексельная честность» западноевропейского буржуа. // *[Б. А. Кистяковский. В защиту права (1909)]*

Nowadays, one would say *должен оберегаться* (or even better *ребёнка нужно оберегать*); *эпигонами доводилось*, etc.

Abusing participle constructs is a sign of poor style. From Nora Gal's *Слово живое и мёртвое*:

> Живой, тем более современной русской речи деепричастия не очень свойственны, и причастными оборотами люди тоже говорят редко, разве что в официальных и торжественных случаях, обычно – читая по бумажке.

She also provides several examples of poor style participle constructs:

> И никто не увидит нас вернувшимися обратно (correct: *очевидно, мы не вернёмся*)
>
> Он... почувствовал себя преследуемым (correct: *ему чудилось, будто его преследуют*)

Comment: Do you have any refs on the poor style note?

Comment: @jwalker: is Nora Gal not authoritative enough?

Comment: @Quassnoi Not as much authoritative as you point. Anyway, she is referring to "live spoken language" not to "poor style" here. Consider "Полковник наш рожден был хватом" vs "Полковник наш родился хватом".

Comment: @user4419802: *рожден был* here is an idiom meaning *прирожденный* "natural". Also, the op and all the examples talk about present participles.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в русском языке глагол "быть" в настоящем времени почти всегда опускается. В том числе и при использовании страдательных причастий.

Во-вторых, только краткое страдательное причастие может быть сказуемым. Т.е. слова "Экзамен сдаваемый учеником" звучат как часть предложения, но не как целое.

В-третьих, в разговорной речи использование распространенных причастных оборотов имеет ограниченный характер. То есть, во многих случаях будет более уместно использовать какую-нибудь равносильную конструкцию, например придаточное предложение: "Экзамен, который сдаёт ученик, ..."

Answer (score -1):

In russian language there is no need to translate 'be'